# Wordpress uploaded image is blank

Tags: c#, image, wordpress, upload, xml-rpc

I'm uploading images to wordpress via communication with xml-rpc using c#.
This is my code on the image conversion. The uploading part works. However when I check the actual image on wordpress, it's a blank picture. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
Byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
Int32 readChars;
while ((readChars = response.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, readChars);
}

MediaObject newBlogImage = new MediaObject();
newBlogImage.bits = ms.ToArray();
newBlogImage.name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + realImageName;
newBlogImage.type = Path.GetExtension(realImageName);
if (newBlogImage.type == "" || newBlogImage.type == ".ashx")
{

    newBlogImage.name = newBlogImage.name + ".jpg";
    newBlogImage.type = ".jpg";
}
info = wrapper.NewMediaObject(newBlogImage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has the same problem, I found the solution. Head over to this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92320e9f-5b9b-481c-bbae-2d9873b47067/how-to-upload-image-to-wordpress-via-xmlrpc-communication-using-c-or-vbnet. Credit goes to  Hetro wong from MSDN forums. Just used Joeblogs UploadImage and everything went well. No need for the codes shown above. Thank you Sir.